# Ejecutar botón desde otra clase

Tags: java, android

Quería saber cómo se puede llamar a un botón desde otra clase, es decir, el botón lo tengo en en activity_main.xml pero, como no me gustaría llenar de código el MainActivity.java, me gustaría poner su código en otra clase, ¿cómo se podría hacer?

Este es mi activity_main.xml

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/boton_web"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="300dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="148dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="275dp" />
```

Este es el MainActivity.java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


}
```

Pues el botón me gustaría declararlo en otra clase java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_boton);

    Button boton_web = (Button) findViewById(R.id.boton_web);

    boton_web.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Uri uri = Uri.parse("https://www.google.es");
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

¿Cómo podría hacerlo?

Comment: Puedes hacerlo de varias formas, pero por lo general se usaría un fragment.
Por si lo desconoces, un fragment es como una sección modular de una actividad que es independiente, recibe sus propios eventos de entrada y que puedes agregar o borrar de tu activity, osea se que es como una especie de "subactividad" que la puedes agregar donde te de la gana.
Por lo que en este caso te puede servir ya que tu puedes tener un fragment.xml con su correspondiente clase java y que ademas lo puedes implementar en tu activity_main.xml.
Perdón por si no me he sabido explicar, te recomiendo de todas formas que

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crea una clase llamada `ButtonWebHelper` y crea un metodo enviadole la referencia del activity para poder utilizar el metodo `startActivity`:

```
public class ButtonWebHelper
{
  public static void abrirWeb(Activity activity)
  {
       Uri uri = Uri.parse("https://www.google.es");
       Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
       activity.startActivity(intent);
  }
}
```

Entonces para utilizarlo solo tendrias que llamar el metodo estatico siempre que necesites abrir la web:

```
 boton_web.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ButtonWebHelper.abrirWeb(ActividadActual.this);
        }
    });
```

Tengo que agregar que aunque tu idea inquietud es valida deberias de tener en cuenta ciertos puntos. Considera encapsular un código que puede ser reutilizado en otra clase siempre y cuando ese codigo sea muy extenso o este propenso a cambios en un futuro. De lo contrario mantelo en su propia clase para evitar futuras confusiones.

Comment: hola buenas!!! ok muchas gracias!!! me ayudo!!